# Producer-Consumer implementation using semaphores and mutex locks in C

Tags: c, mutex, semaphore, producer-consumer

I am using the following code to to implement a basic prod-consumer problem in C. On rare occasions though, i'm getting wrong outputs such as mentioned below.

The Received value reaches 0, but when it reaches 0 when there are still producer cycles to be left, then the receiver keeps getting 0 values and the output goes awry.

Please help me understand what is wrong with my code. Thanks.

**C CODE:**

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
sem_t semaphore;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int queue[50];
int queueLength;
void *producer( void * param)
{
    for ( int i=0; i<50; i++ )
    {
        // Add item to queue
        pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex );
        queue[ queueLength++ ] = i;
        printf("Sent %d\n", i);
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex );
        // Signal semaphore

        sem_post( &semaphore );
    }
}
void *consumer(void * param)
{
    for ( int i=0; i<50; i++ )
    {
        int item;
        // Wait if nothing in queue
        if (queueLength<1) { sem_wait(&semaphore); }
        pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex );
        item = queue[ -- queueLength ];
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex );
        printf("Received %i\n", item);
    }
}
int main()
{
    pthread_t threads[2];
    sem_init( &semaphore, 0, 1 );
    pthread_create( &threads[0], 0, producer, 0 );
    pthread_create( &threads[1], 0, consumer, 0 );
    pthread_join( threads[0], 0 );
    pthread_join( threads[1], 0 );
    sem_destroy( &semaphore );
}
```

**Wrong Output:**

```
Sent 0
Sent 1
Sent 2
Sent 3
Sent 4
Sent 5
Sent 6
Sent 7
Sent 8
Sent 9
Sent 10
Sent 11
Sent 12
Sent 13
Sent 14
Sent 15
Sent 16
Sent 17
Sent 18
Sent 19
Sent 20
Sent 21
Sent 22
Sent 23
Sent 24
Sent 25
Sent 26
Sent 27
Sent 28
Received 28
Received 27
Received 26
Received 25
Received 24
Received 23
Received 22
Received 21
Received 20
Received 19
Received 18
Received 17
Received 16
Received 15
Received 14
Received 13
Received 12
Received 11
Received 10
Received 9
Received 8
Received 7
Received 6
Received 5
Received 4
Received 3
Received 2
Received 1
Received 0
Received 0
Received 0
Received 0
Received 0
Received 0
Received 0
Received 0
Received -8
Received 0
Received 0
Received 0
Received 0
Received 0
Received 0
Received 0
Received 0
Received 0
Received 0
Received 0
Received 0
Received 1
Sent 29
Sent 30
Sent 31
Sent 32
Sent 33
Sent 34
Sent 35
Sent 36
Sent 37
Sent 38
Sent 39
Sent 40
Sent 41
Sent 42
Sent 43
Sent 44
Sent 45
Sent 46
Sent 47
Sent 48
Sent 49
```

Comment: Have you considered using condition variables? I'm gussing you dont want to look at solutions to this problem and want to solve them yourself. Check out pthread_cond_wait/pthread_cond_signal. This would help with what you are doing I think.

Comment: why do you need semaphores? If there is only 1 threat that writes and 1 that reads you are fine. You only need to make sure that only if the write is completed the read is able to read. Incrementing the length should be the last stap.

Comment: 'if (queueLength<1)' NO!  TOCTTOU disaster.

Comment: @MaartenArits he uses a semaphore to count the items in the queue.  If there is no semaphore, what will the consumer wait on if there is no items in the queue?

Comment: True, you could use signals for that but semaphores work just as well than

Comment: Never ever use `sem_wait` without checking for the return value. This call can be interrupted, e.g when there is IO, so you always *must* check if the wait was successful.

Comment: @FrancoSolleza Yeah, I am trying to understand what goes wrong here, because the logic seemed correct from a layman's point of view. Thanks, i'll read up on pthread_cond.

Comment: @maarten I understand semaphores may not be needed, but the main purpose here for me was to understand and implement semaphores. :)

Comment: @martin Even I thought there was something wrong between `if (queueLength<1)` and`mutex_lock` , but can you please elaborate what could exactly be happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the time your consumer thread starts, semaphore has already been signaled, and `queueLength` is larger than zero. Your consumer thread will immediately start dequeueing (since `queueLength` isn't zero), until it reaches zero.

As soon as the queue is depleted, in the next consumer loop iteration (with `queueLength == 0`), it will enter the `if` clause and try to wait on the semaphore (which has been already signaled), and acquire the lock immediately.

So the semaphore cannot be inside the `if` condition, meaning you could use something like:

```
for ( int i=0; i<50; i++ )
{
    int item;

    // wait for signal
    sem_wait(&semaphore);

    pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex );
    item = queue[--queueLength];
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex );
    printf("Received %i\n", item);
}
```

My suggestion (if this is your actual problem) would be to create a simple circular buffer instead. If implemented properly (i.e. only a single producer, single consumer, if the producer only moves the `head`, and the consumer only moves the `tail`, and presuming both variables are `int` or smaller -- i.e. can be read and written atomically), you won't need the `mutex` at all (only the semaphore for signalization).

The array named `queue` in your example is actually a *stack* (LIFO), which is unusual in producer/consumer patterns where you usually want to dequeue and process oldest items first.

Comment: 'if (queueLength < 1)' - redundant, since that condition is not possible.

Comment: @MartinJames: you're right, my bad, it's redundant with OP's code. If there were multiple producers/consumers, the check (inside the mutex) would be necessary, but then again having a `for` loop in the consumer wouldn't make sense.

Comment: No - even with multiple producers/consumers, one semaphore and one mutex is sufficient for an unbounded P-C queue without any queue checking.  Preventing overflow of a bounded queue would require another semaphore or some other design that prevents queue overflow, (I only use unbounded queues:).

Comment: @MartinJames: yeah, you're right again, I guess it's time to go to sleep.

Comment: I was under the impression that I'm decrementing the semaphore each time an iteration of the consumer runs. didn't realise it's only happening when the `queueLength` becomes 0.
With the edit that you mentioned, in its current implementation is my code free from any possible errors?

Comment: That was a noob-error, implementing a queue named array as a stack, but let's assume that the consumer here wants to have the freshest items first.

Comment: @martin I understand now that the condition `if (queueLength < 1)` is redundant. Thanks.

Comment: @UtkarshAgarwal: I will add some comments later today or tomorrow, I am in a bit of a rush right now.

Comment: @Groo No problem sir, anytime. Eagerly waiting to learn anything new. Semaphores seem a very interesting topic to me anyway.